# VSCode Ctrl+Space Not Bringing Up Class Options For Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> while inside the parenthesis of a class, but getting no hints.
I have the flutter extension (which includes dart) installed.
Screenshot attached from Keyboard Shortcuts search.
How can I fix this?

pubspec.yaml

```
name: app_name
description: Generic Description.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

[image: Screenshot]

Folder Structure
[image]

Enabled extensions
[image]

Two Problems
[image]

Comment: Are you opening individual `.dart` files in VSCode or an entire directory with a `pubspec.yaml` at the root?

Comment: @benKonyi Just while editing the main.dart file

Comment: post a screenshot of the ide with the project structure open on the side and the issue.

Comment: what hint are you missing? looks like the dart analyzer is working fine.

Comment: The directory structure looks like it's okay... that's odd. Can you also share your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Added - this is basically the default new app generated automatically.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured, but it's better to be thorough. Everything seems to be fine. The only thing I can think of is that the analysis server crashed or isn't running. Are there any errors in your status bar?

Comment: @benkonyi - 2 Problems (image added), but I am not sure they would cause this

Comment: Yeah, those wouldn't cause any of the errors. Can you check the bell icon in the bottom right to see if there's any notifications? It does look like the analyzer is working if you're seeing those errors in `widget_test.dart` though...

Comment: @BenKoni No new notifications

Comment: Hm, then the last thing I can think of is restarting VSCode and hoping for the best. If that doesn't work, you might want to file an issue on the [dart-code GitHub repo](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code) and they might be able to help you more.

Comment: @BenKonyi - Tried that with no luck. Thanks for sticking with me. I may just have to memorize everything. :-)

Comment: Ah darn! Not a problem, sorry that didn't fix it! Hopefully it fixes itself at some point... :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue when I enabled a different language for my keyboard on my Mac. Notice that the shortcut for "Select the previous input source" is Ctrl Space. Turning that off solved my problem.

[image: Keyboard settings window on Mac, after searching for 'Keyboard' in the spotlight search]

Answer (score 2):

Static analysis doesn't work in VSCode (potentially even other editors, but I haven't tried) unless you've got an entire Dart project opened at its root (e.g., the folder that contains your `pubspec.yaml`). This is because the `dartanalyzer` doesn't have the context of the entire program, which would make it impossible to provide autocompletion for classes and other code that live in another file.

It's annoying when you just want to edit a single file and perform code completion for code defined within the file, but that's unfortunately how it works at this point in time.

Comment: I have the entire root folder open in VSCode and am editing a single file from there. Is that what I should be doing?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your project directory structure? This is typically the solution to this issue when I run into it.

Comment: image added to the issue

Answer (score 1):

The common reasons in case you are not getting hints.

1. Not opening the root folder which contains the project, and just opening the single which you want to edit.
2. You want hints from code in another file that does not have the changes saved yet. So, if the new code is not saved it won't provide a hint.
3. You IDE is ignoring the file because it is somehow excluded in the folder(*marked by IDE as excluded*)

Answer (score 0):

I had multi-language keyboard.. so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut is used to change keyboard language.

To change shortcut for showing class options .. In **VSCode** go to **Code** menu -> **prefrences** -> **keyboard shortcuts** -> Then look for (**Trigger Suggest**) and change it to a different key combination.

[image]

Also you will find other shortcuts too that can do the same function .. for me I have this list

[image]